# "Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middlewar?"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Learning node.js encountered this error "Login sessions require session support. Did you forget to use `express-session` middlewar?" Has anyone encountered this specific error when creating a Node.js project and, if so, what did you do to solve?

```
const express = require('express');

const cors = require('cors');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const passport = require('passport');

const path = require('path');

const config = require('./config/db');

const account = require('./routes/account');

const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());


mongoose.connect(config.db);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log("Successful connection to the database")
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log("Not successful connection to the database")
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("The server was running on the port: " + port)
});

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Home page")
});

app.use('/account', account);


const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/user');

const passport = require('passport');

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const config = require('../config/db');


router.post('/reg', (req,res) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        login:req.body.login,
        password: req.body.password,
    }); 





    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if(err) {
            res.json({success: false, msg: "User has not been added."})
        }
        else {
            res.json({success: true, msg: "User has been added"})
        }
    })
});



router.get('/auth', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Login page")
});

router.get('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session : false}), (req,res) => {
    res.send("Dashboard")
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 10):

The error is asking a relevant question: *"Did you forget to use express-session middleware?"*.

And indeed, you're loading `passport.session()` but you're not using `express-session`, which is a requirement.

To fix it, use `express-session` *before* using `passport.session()`:

```
app.use(session({ … }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. My issue was that `app.use(session({...}))` was called after passport initialization.

Comment: what do we put inside the {...} ?

Comment: @NikhilVJ read the documentation for `express-session`

Answer (score 5):

I faced same problem. But the real problem lied in the "passport" version compatibility with JWT module. By downgrading from passport 0.8.0 to 0.4.0 the issue was easily resolved. My code worked fine with the following configuration:

```
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1",
"session-file-store": "^1.5.0"
```

Comment: The same worked for me. Simply change the passport version to "passport": "^0.4.0" in package.json file and run npm install. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I'm using passport google Oauth and JWT token without session. In order to solve this error, I had to set the session to false in google callback. Here is my example:

```
  router. Get(
    "/googleLogin/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      session: false,
      failureRedirect: frontEndUrl + "/user/login",
    }),
    expressAsyncHandler((req, res) => {
      setAccessTokenCookie(req.user, res);
      res.redirect(frontEndUrl);
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a high enough reputation to add a comment to the answer telling you to downgrade your passport version, but doing so can introduce vulnerabilities...

Instead, look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport and see if your app has this: (version 0.6.0)

```
var app = express();
app.use(require('serve-static')(__dirname + '/../../public'));
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

For me, the fix was telling express to use 'express-session'.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you included the following line in your `app.js`:

```js
app.use(require('express-session')({ 
  secret: 'Enter your secret key',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Adding this line solved the issue for me.